# overwriting hive partition by a spark dataframe

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have a hive table partitioned on snapshot_dt

I have to delete records from each partition which have turned 180 days old or 7 years old depending on condition.

I am iterating over each partition one by one inside for loop
selecting all the records from the partition into whole_data_df dataframe
selecting records to be deleted into save_to_data dataframe

using except to get the records I want.

```
var cons_rec_to_retain_df = whole_data_df.except(save_to_data)
```

now I want to overwrite that particular hive partition with the records in the dataframe cons_rec_to_retain_df.

Please find my code below

```
var query5=s"""select distinct snapshot_dt from workspace_x215579.ess_consldt_cust_prospect_ord_orc_test"""
var partition_load_dates = createDataframeFromSql(hc,query5)
var output = partition_load_dates.collect().toList
output.foreach(println)

for (d1<- output){

var partition_date:String=d1(0).toString
println("=====================this is the partition date========================")
println(partition_date)
var whole_data = s"""select * From workspace_x215579.ess_consldt_cust_prospect_ord_orc_test where snapshot_dt='$partition_date'"""
println("=====================this is whole partition data df========================")
var whole_data_df = createDataframeFromSql(hc,whole_data)
whole_data_df.show(5,false)

var select_data = s"""select * From workspace_x215579.ess_consldt_cust_prospect_ord_orc_test where snapshot_dt='$partition_date'
                                and
                                bus_bacct_num_src_id = 130
                                and
                                (bacct_status_cd = 'T' and datediff(to_date(current_timestamp()), snapshot_dt) > 180)
                                OR
                                (bacct_status_cd <> 'T' and cast(datediff(to_date(current_timestamp()), snapshot_dt)/365.25 as int) > 7)
                                """
                                var save_to_data = createDataframeFromSql(hc,select_data)
                                println("=====================this is df to be removed========================")



save_to_data.show(5,false)
                                var cons_rec_to_retain_df = whole_data_df.except(save_to_data)

                                 println("=====================this is df REcord to be inserted=======================")
                                 cons_rec_to_retain_df.show(5,false)







println("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!")


cons_rec_to_retain_df.show(5)
cons_rec_to_retain_df.write.mode("append").format("orc").insertInto("workspace_x215579.ess_consldt_cust_prospect_ord_orc_test")
```

}//end of for loop

In the starting I am setting

```
 hc.sql("""set hive.exec.dynamic.partition=true""")
    hc.sql("""set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict""")
```

after running the code the count of the record is same as was before. Can someone please suggest a proper way of doing it.

Comment: will solution in pyspark work?

Comment: first try setting below property also spark.conf.set("spark.sql.sources.partitionOverwriteMode","dynamic")